# Could not get out of python loop 

Tags: python, sockets, loops

I want to get out of loop when there is no data but loop seems to be stopping at `recvfrom`

```
image=''
while 1:
        data,address=self.socket.recvfrom(512)
        if data is None:break
        image=image+data
        count=count+1
        print str(count)+' packets received...'
```

Comment: What do you mean by stopping? Does the program crash or does it hang?

Comment: Have you set the socket to non-blocking mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting to a [non-blocking socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking).  You would do this before the loop starts.  You can also try a [socket with a timeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout).

Answer (score 2):

`recvfrom` may indeed stop (waiting for data) unless you've set your socket to non-blocking or timeout mode. Moreover, if the socket gets closed by your counterpart, the indication of "socket was closed, nothing more to receive" is **not** a value of `None` for `data` -- it's an empty string, `''`. So you could change your test to `if not data: break` for more generality.

Answer (score 0):

What is the blocking mode of your socket?

If you are in blocking mode (which I think is the default), your program would stop until data is available... You would then not get to the next line after the recv() until data is coming.

If you switch to non-blocking mode, however (see socket.setblocking(flag)), I think that it will raise an exception you would have to catch rather than null-check.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set socket.setdefaulttimeout(n) to get out of the loop if no data is returned after specified time period.